# Update MySite properties when Facebook is used as an Identity Provider

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am using Facebook as Identity provider to log in to SharePoint 2013. And it is achieved successfully. User can log-in to SharePoint using Facebook Credentials.

Now i want to update MySite profile with User Logged in via Facebook.

E.g. Update Birthdate property with data fetched from Facebook.

[I followed this article but it uses a web part to update properties](http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2012/05/programmatically-updating-sharepoint-user-profiles-with-facebook-data/). How can i update properties on user sign-in to SharePoint and MySite properties get updated at that time only ? i.e As Soon as user signs in with Facebook as Identity provider, it will check for mapped UserProfile properties and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you out to get the work done
http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/12/25/authenticate-your-sharepoint-website-users-with-facebook.aspx

Comment: Thanks for link. But this step is already performed. As mentioned in question that Authentication phase is completed. Now, i need to update properties which can be displayed in MySite.